# Correct way to use a left drawable with a button

Tags: android, button, drawable

I want to achive something like this
[image]

```
 <Button
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_facebook"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Login with facebook"
        android:background="@color/facebook_theme_primary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The problem with this is that if the image is bigger, it will be too big and make the button larger.
I want to make it fit just like in the photo above..

My output is this

[image]

What is the best way to achive this, and is posible from XML?

Full layout XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:flatui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".HomeActivity">

<Button
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_facebook"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Login with facebook"
    android:background="@color/facebook_theme_primary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Probably some issue with its parent layout OR facebook image. Same code works fine for me. Post containing layout if possible.

Comment: Done. Note: i'm using Nexus 4 as preview device of my layout, same thing happens on phone  / emulator.

Comment: See [paste](http://pastebin.com/XwmPpN5t) and [image](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=7c79958)

Comment: Check image size and use proper simension image as that of ic_launcher. e.g. 72x72 px for hdpi, etc.

Comment: @MysticMagic because your image is small. Mine is bigger. I don't want to depend of my image size..

Comment: With a smaller image, everything is scaled how I want to, but the icon is blurred a little bit. Thanks for the guy with the downvote.

Comment: Then try to work on image quality and size. Coz rest code looks fine.. I didn't downvote by the way :)

Comment: I've answered my question, I found the solution :)

Comment: Great.. accept your own answer. so its removed from unanswered list. happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to use  **layout_weight** property inside **horizontal LinearLayout**

Comment: This will make the same result as A Honey Bustard's answer. The size of the button will be different, but the image will be out of the view.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with LinearLayout and set OnClickListener another solution would be something like :

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="20dp"
```

the 20dp is just guessing, try until you get the correct size

Comment: I've used 50. The problem is that the image is out of the view , i want to make it fit.. http://i.snag.gy/sb1ds.jpg

Comment: Try using an ImageButton instead of a Button and set the image with android:src"@drawable/..."

Comment: The image will be in center, instead of the left. And same output.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there is no solution for my problem via XML.

What I need to do is create the normal button, without the image and from java code add the image.

```
     Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_facebook);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int) (button.getHeight()),
            (int) (button.getHeight()   )); // yes, i know (int)(int) is redundant, you can remove the cast if you are only using integers
    button.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, null, null, null); // this will set the left drawable
```

In my case, the image was a square. If you want your image to be smaller, just multiply the size by 0.X ..,

```
 drawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int) (button.getHeight() * 0.5),
            (int) (button.getHeight() *0.5  ));
```

If your image is not a square I suggest scalling it to fit the height..

```
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int) (button.getHeight()),
            (int) (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() / drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() * button.getHeight()));
```

**Note**
Only use this in the onWindowFocusChanged method. Why? In the onCreate method the button width / height is 0.